# Do PHP scripts work if htaccess url rewrite is implemented?

Tags: php, .htaccess

If I use mod-rewrite to change a url like this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/page.php?title=my-name-is-john
```

to

```
http://www.mysite.com/page/my-name-is-john
```

and if the page.php file contains a script that relies on parameters passed through the url like:

```
$_GET['title'];
```

Then will that script still work after the mod-rewrite has been implemented?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, mod rewrite is transparent to the php scripts. So for the script it seems was just requested with the old url.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Your script will still work.

(ModRewrite is essentially transparent to PHP/and other CGIs you run.)